# Mimic Tkinter file open in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I have worked mostly with Tkinter before and I used the following code to store path of file I selected. After exploring Kivy, it doesn't seem like Kivy have a simple function like this. So I tried using the filechoser instead

```
path = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select file")
```

Main code is very simple

```
class checker_ui(GridLayout):
    def findreport(self,path):
        pass



class Checker(App):
    def build(self):
        return checker_ui()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Checker().run()
```

Then I created a .kv file just to see what filechooser looks like. The script would just open and freeze.

```
<checker_ui>:
    BoxLayout:
        FileChooserIconLayout:
            id:filechooser
            on_selection:root.select(*args)
```

Here is the output

[image: Freeze]

I search all over the place and did not see anyone with a similar issue. Is there an alternative I can try to mimic the tkinter behaviour or am I stuck with this issue? I'm on a Windows machine and normal kivy widget works, ie: button,label etc.

Answer (score 0):

so I wrote a lot more code than you (based heavily on the kivy example @ https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.filechooser.html#usage-example)

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""
#:kivy 1.1.0

<Root>:
    text_input: text_input

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 30
            Button:
                text: 'Load'
                on_release: root.show_load()
            Button:
                text: 'Save'
                on_release: root.show_save()

        BoxLayout:
            TextInput:
                id: text_input
                text: ''

            RstDocument:
                text: text_input.text
                show_errors: True

<LoadDialog>:
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        pos: root.pos
        orientation: "vertical"
        FileChooserListView:
            id: filechooser

        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 30
            Button:
                text: "Cancel"
                on_release: root.cancel()

            Button:
                text: "Load"
                on_release: root.load(filechooser.path, filechooser.selection)

<SaveDialog>:
    text_input: text_input
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        pos: root.pos
        orientation: "vertical"
        FileChooserListView:
            id: filechooser
            on_selection: text_input.text = self.selection and self.selection[0] or ''

        TextInput:
            id: text_input
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 30
            multiline: False

        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 30
            Button:
                text: "Cancel"
                on_release: root.cancel()

            Button:
                text: "Save"
                on_release: root.save(filechooser.path, text_input.text)""")
import os


class LoadDialog(FloatLayout):
    load = ObjectProperty(None)
    cancel = ObjectProperty(None)


class SaveDialog(FloatLayout):
    save = ObjectProperty(None)
    text_input = ObjectProperty(None)
    cancel = ObjectProperty(None)


class Root(FloatLayout):
    loadfile = ObjectProperty(None)
    savefile = ObjectProperty(None)
    text_input = ObjectProperty(None)

    def dismiss_popup(self):
        self._popup.dismiss()

    def show_load(self):
        content = LoadDialog(load=self.load, cancel=self.dismiss_popup)
        self._popup = Popup(title="Load file", content=content,
                            size_hint=(0.9, 0.9))
        self._popup.open()

    def show_save(self):
        content = SaveDialog(save=self.save, cancel=self.dismiss_popup)
        self._popup = Popup(title="Save file", content=content,
                            size_hint=(0.9, 0.9))
        self._popup.open()

    def load(self, path, filename):
        with open(os.path.join(path, filename[0])) as stream:
            self.text_input.text = stream.read()

        self.dismiss_popup()

    def save(self, path, filename):
        with open(os.path.join(path, filename), 'w') as stream:
            stream.write(self.text_input.text)

        self.dismiss_popup()


class Editor(App):
    def build(self):
        return Root()




if __name__ == '__main__':
    Editor().run()
```

Comment: I did try the example, and the machine would freeze after clicking load. I was trying to go with a minimalist tactic to see if it works this way. Could be something with my machine.

Comment: hmmm it worked for me ... you copied and pasted this and didnt edit it at all and it froze? are you using an older version of kivy? are you sure you installed all the kivy dependencies? are you running with normal CPython? what version of Python? are you running through cygwin or something? are you running some other variant of python (anaconda/cython/pipython/etc)?

Comment: I restarted and got it to load, but the file name started to overlap on one another when I'm clicking.

Comment: After reading through the example and manipulate a few lines I was able to get it working.Though it's working but I got this error pywintypes.error: (32, 'GetFileAttributesEx', 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.') have you seen this before?

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

1. Replace *FileChooserIconLayout* with *FileChooserIconView*
2. Add a *BoxLayout* and make *FileChooserIconView* a children of the *BoxLayout*

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout


class Checker_ui(GridLayout):

    def findreport(self, path):
        print("path=", path)


class Checker(App):

    def build(self):
        return Checker_ui()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Checker().run()
```

### checker.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<Checker_ui>:
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        pos: root.pos
        orientation: "vertical"
        FileChooserIconView:
            id: filechooser
            on_selection: root.select(*args)
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - AppStartup]

Comment: I got an error after selecting a file. The variable path doesn't seem to tie to anything.

Answer (score 0):

Hey if anyone wants to open all types of file just use(mp4,jpg,pdf,txt,docs...etc)

import webbrowser

webbrowser.open(filename[0])